# Call schema method in jade/pug script code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

I have a collection with `mongoose`.

I have added a method to the schema.

The problem is that I use all my documents in javascript code with `jade` using this code snippet

```
script.
  var nodes = !{JSON.stringify(nodes)};
```

but now `nodes` is populated with an array of objects, and I am no longer able to call my schema method, i.e. it is not possible to do this

```
script.
  var nodes = !{JSON.stringify(nodes)};
  nodes = nodes.map(function (node) {
    return node.generateFullName()
  });
```

because each object only stores the values and thus not the schema method. The code snippet above will result in error `node.generateFullName is not a function`.

What can I do to call the `generateFullName()` function in javascript? It works fine in normal templates

```
each node in nodes
  p= node.generateFullName()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `JSON.stringify`-ed data is an array detached from the schema and its methods, you will either need to add code in the template to replicate the `generateFullName` method on the client side, or more simply, you can move your map function inside the interpolated `JSON.stringify` call like this:

```
 !{JSON.stringify(nodes.map(function(node) { return node.generateFullName(); })};
```